# Retrieving String from JAX-RS Response

Tags: java, request, jax-rs, response

In short terms, I simplified the problem *a lot*. I am calling this code, and the response is received with status 200 (OK):

**Receiver.java**:

```
Response response = componentInstanceService.getResource(componentResourceType);
```

However, I don't know how can I retrieve the String contained in the body from this method:

**Sender.java:**

```
  @Override
    public Response getResource(ComponentResourceType resourceType) {
        String path = getPath();
        return Response.ok(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)).build();
    }
```

Please note that the communication between classes is working fine, as long as the `Response` is OK, however, how can I retrieve the `String` that `Response` contains?

This is what I would like to do roughly:

**Receiver:**

```
String result = componentInstanceService.getResource(componentResourceType);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for Response](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) makes this pretty clear:

> `static Response.ResponseBuilder ok(java.lang.Object entity)`
>
> Create a new ResponseBuilder that contains a representation.

And:

> `abstract java.lang.Object getEntity()`
>
> Return the response entity.

In other words, the object you passed to `Response.ok` is the entity.  You can retrieve it with the Response’s getEntity() method.

Obviously, you will need to cast it:

```
Response response = componentInstanceService.getResource(componentResourceType);
InputStream dataSource = (InputStream) response.getEntity();
```

Then you can read the stream as text.  You haven’t mentioned the charset of your text files, so I’ll assume it’s UTF-8:

```
String result;
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataSource, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    result = scanner.useDelimiter("\\z").next();
}
```

**Update:**

I suspected this might happen.  You are returning a raw InputStream, which has no information about what type of data it is.

Change Sender.java to return a DataSource:

```
@Override
public DataSource getResource(ComponentResourceType resourceType) {
    String path = getPath();
    return new URLDataSource(this.getClass().getResource(path));
}
```

This way, the JAX-RS service will not only return HTTP 200 OK, but will also return a Content-Type header corresponding to the intuited type of your file.

You should then be able to invoke the method with:

```
DataSource dataSource = componentInstanceService.getResource(componentResourceType);

String result;
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataSource.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    result = scanner.useDelimiter("\\z").next();
}
```

There actually is a more robust way to read a DataSource.  You can wrap it in a DataHandler:

```
DataSource dataSource = componentInstanceService.getResource(componentResourceType);
DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(dataSource);

DataFlavor flavor = DataFlavor.selectBestTextFlavor(
    handler.getTransferDataFlavors());

if (flavor == null) {
    // This should never happen with text files.
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Data has no flavors capable of supplying text.");
}

String result;
try (Reader reader = flavor.getReaderForText(handler)) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    int c;
    while ((c = reader.read()) >= 0) {
        s.append((char) c);
    }
    result = s.toString();
} catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
    // Since we started with a flavor provided by the DataHandler,
    // we should never get here.
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: which import are you using for InputStream? I am going to try it, thanks a lot

Comment: thanks, but I am getting JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.RuntimeException: No type information to extract entity with, use other getEntity() methods

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the string from the body simply use

```
String result = componentInstanceService.getResource(componentResourceType).readEntity(String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it is not working. I am getting: JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Comment: How do you invoke the service? Are you using Jersey client? Did you verify that your service is working by invoking your sender with curl ect.?

Comment: I am invoking it as I shown in the question I posted, but it breaks in the line you suggested with the aforementioned error

Comment: Sounds like the server is running with Java EE 6.

Comment: It is. How can I retrieve it running with Java EE6? @VGR

Comment: What pom dependency should I have? @simdevmon

Comment: If your service is exposed as http you can use Jersey client to receive the values: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html

Comment: @simdevmon what POM.XML dependency are you using for that readEntity?

Comment: @VGR Should I use any other particular dependency?